# VB.NET Could not load file or assembly 'EnterpriseASPClient' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to launch an already made asp.net web app, but even though I followed all the steps I still get this error, what could be the reason or solution to this. Google hasn't been of help much so am kinda desperate. Will really appreciate any help, thanks in advance and here is the error page.
[image: ASP.NET error page]

Answer (score 1):

"an already made asp.net web app". Maybe you only have the code, not the dll referenced on it. Check the proyect references.

If I was right then, maybe here you can get that DLL:
http://pusatborong.dyndns.org/Enterprise/EnterpriseASPClient/

Comment: Thanks for the site but i dont know how i can access the directory structure of Enterprise/enterpriseASP because only then can I know what I am missing, its redirecting me to login page instead of the file structure

Comment: Did you try for example:
http://pusatborong.dyndns.org/Enterprise/EnterpriseASPClient/obj/Release/EnterpriseASPClient.dll ?

Comment: Still didn't fix it, I think Imma have to ask my boss if He has another version, a more complete one because this one looks messed up